# How to avoid NullPointerException when using custom Views or SurfaceViews

Tags: android, custom-controls, nullpointerexception

I created a custom `SurfaceView` called `CaptureView` and tried to add it into `main.xml` file:

```
<dev.recorder.client.CaptureView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/capturePreview"/>
```

The application seems to work fine but if I switch from `main.xml` tab to Layout in Eclipse the text `NullPointerException` appears instead of layout preview.

In the Activity I binded the controls the following way:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);

    bindControls();

private void bindControls()
{
    videoPreview = (CaptureView)findViewById(R.id.capturePreview);

    txtstatus = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtMode);
    txtTimer = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtTime);
}
```

Does anyone know how this issue could be solved?

Comment: So is the problem just that it isn't giving you the preview properly in Eclipse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make sure that you are initializing the view in onFinishInflate and not in the constructor.
the layout preview code might initialize your control through a different code path.